# Merging identically-named folders from separate branches in Subversion

Tags: svn

I'm running into an odd issue with a project tracked in Subversion. I have both the trunk and a stable branch - the stable branch has a particular folder, (let's call it /a) that I created a few weeks ago and has a few code files in it. Meanwhile, a few days ago, another developer I work with created her own identically named /a folder in trunk (same path and everything) and put a different file in it. Put another way, the current structure looks like this

/trunk
  /a
    FileYellow
/branches
  /stable
    /a
      FileRed
      FileBlue
      FileGreen

When I try to merge my changes from the stable branch into trunk, I get a tree conflict based on the /a folder. I think this makes sense, since both folders were independently created and committed and SVN has no way of knowing which one to use. I'd expect that I'd at least be able to select either trunk or the stable branch's /a structure (including the files) when resolving the conflict though, but none of the files from the stable branch's /a directory ever get merged into the working directory. About the only thing I can do is resolve the current state of the working directory using `svn resolve --accept working -R <path>`

At this point I'm considering just performing an svn delete on the /a folder in trunk so that I can merge in the stable /a (and its files) and then re-adding the single file that was originally in trunk. I'm just wondering if there's a better, more elegant way to handle this particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

The Natural Way for such "pseudo-tree conflicts" is

1. Merge conflicting subtree only (`cd trunk/a && merge ^/branches/stable/a .`)
2. Merge full tree

Maybe remove mergeinfo after second merge from `/a` by hand (if not cleaned automatically, as it must happen)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try this I'm getting a "<repository URL>/branches/stable/a@<revision> must be ancestrally related to <repository URL>/trunk/a@<revision>" error now. I'm guessing that even though I'm now doing the merge within the conflicted folder, it's still looking at the parent /a folder and realizing that they're unrelated. Just out of curiosity I tried throwing in an --ignore-ancestry flag, but that also triggers an error: "Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo"

Am I missing something or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: And yes, this whole experience is making me very excited to move things over to Mercurial or Git as soon as possible.

Comment: @MTB2013 - 1) I tested **exactly** your case before posting answer - I could merge a without errors (SVN 1.8.11). 2) Git - strong "no-no", trust me